# Google Play is not showing correct download count for my app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have published a android app at google play 3 weeks back.
This app has its own DB running at server. So, basically i know the number of downloads this app has made.(as i generate unique number for each device).

Now, google play is showing download count as 258 till 28th April, where as the actual download count should be 4000+(as per my DB).
I am pretty sure my DB is showing correct, as i also have 1000+ unique email IDs registered to my app.
i also mailed help center, but all they are saying is that "they do not validate against third party statistics at this time".
So, what should i do ? I also checked internet and found some posts for same problems in 2010, but no solution.

Please help me if you have any idea..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google might be a few days off or be invalidating some installations for reasons you can't know because that is internal logic of theirs.

The installation count is an estimate, a number given by Google that you should trust but that you cannot verify, right?

Your DB seems reliable because it did not create those emails from thin air.

The problem here is the huge gap between your count and Google's.

I would say Google count will catch up and that your count is the correct total installation that occurred and that you should use.

Comment: I understand if there is any delay in updating count. But it should update right ? They did not just missed for a day, they are missing counts day after day. Also, they are not ready to raise a bug for this.

Comment: That is what I wrote. I cannot talk for Google. I just told you what I know. Of course your numbers (except if a bug is present) should be more "safe" to use since you have control over it, while you don't know how *Google counts*.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also happened to me, 
statistics they use to count different than your database.
and is not always trustworthy.